# Contact Context in Mobile Connect with Phone Numbers

Tags: ampscript, mobileconnect

Say a contact can exist more than once in a DE with different sub key, but same phone number. An sms is sent to one of them as an Outbound SMS (MT). This SMS is linked to a "Next Keyword". In that second SMS (the one that handles a response to the Outbound SMS, is there any way to determine which contact the first message was sent to? Ie, how I can get context of the right contact in the response handler?

I have tried to output things like %%_ContactID%%, or even %%_Source%%, but everything is blank.

If i view the Contact (from All Contacts, I can see the value of "Contact ID" under the "Mobile Demographics" data set.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this will work but have you tried subscriberid